# Why aren't bearings aligning in proper azimuths in plot?

Tags: r, bearing, plotrix

I am using plotrix package in R. The `polar.plot` function allows me to plot frequency of targets per bearing. I have this example:

```
library(plotrix)
ex <- c(100,100,100,100,100,120,120,140,150,170,200,200,200,200)
tex <- table(ex) 
polar.plot(as.numeric(tex), start = 90, clockwise = TRUE, 
   line.col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

Can you try this? I'm having trouble figuring out why they do not align properly.

Comment: I should provide more info....

Comment: check that your plot has an aspect ratio of 1:1 (`?par`, search for `asp`, or check out `MASS::eqscplot`)

Comment: library(plotrix) 
polar.plot(as.numeric(tex), start = 90, clockwise = TRUE, line.col = "blue", lwd = 2) 
ex <- c(100,100,100,100,100,120,120,140,150,170,200,200,200,200) tex <- table(ex)

can you try this? I'm having trouble figuring out why they do not align properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `polar.pos` argument:

```
 polar.plot(as.numeric(tex), 
     polar.pos=as.numeric(names(tex)), start = 90, clockwise = TRUE, 
     line.col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```